# Gulp task runs much faster without 'return' statement - why is that?

Tags: build, return, task, gulp

Gulp task formed like this (without `return`) runs much faster:

```
gulp.task('less', function () {
  gulp.src('./less/**/*.less')
   .pipe(less())
   .pipe(gulp.dest('./destination'));
});
```

than the same one with `return`:

```
gulp.task('less', function () {
  return gulp.src('./less/**/*.less')
   .pipe(less())
   .pipe(gulp.dest('./destination'));
});
```

So, my question is what does Gulp task is supposed to `return`? Why is it so much faster without `return`, while it still generates expected files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some investigation I found that when `return` is used on Gulp task it's not actually slower at all, it just returns correct time it took to finish the task.

It only felt faster since without `return` statement it essentially returned result as *completed* almost instantly, so the task time looked like few ms, but the actual process continued on the background and completed silently.

So, it's safe to say that it's prefferable to use `return` on all your tasks that have `gulp.src()`.